# Access to data for JDBC query in ViewPanel on XPage via OpenNTF driver

Tags: xpages, lotus-notes, xpages-ssjs, mssql-jdbc, xpinc

We have an XPage which is using a named JDBC connection via the OpenNTF extension library.

This is successfully retrieving data and placing it inside a View Panel, I've selected to display a Check Box next to first field in the Row, and need to access the returned value for that field in that row (or an array for multiples of the selected rows).

So far have tried these methods:

```
var Docs2=getComponent("viewPanelDocs");
//var db2 = Docs2.getAttributes();
//var doc2Array=Docs2.getSelectedIds();
//var test = getComponent("something");
var p=Docs2.getParent()
var pp=something.getColumnValue("extName")
var Rows = Docs2.getChildCount().valueOf();
var doc2Array= new Array();
var SelectedDocs2 = new Array();
for(i=0; i < Rows; i++) {
        // Works, no output: var Selected2Docs=Docs2.getAttributes();
        // FAILS: var Selected2Docs=Docs2_xspGetRendererData();
        // WORKS, no output: var Selected2Docs=Docs2._xspGetRendererData();
        // WORKS, gets local ID of viewPanel: var Selected2Docs=Docs2.getId();
        // Works: javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase$AttributesMap@0: var Selected2Docs=Docs2.getAttributes();
        // FAILS, doesn't like string: var Selected2Docs=Docs2.getAttributes("ExternalUNCLink");
        // WOrks, no output: var Selected2Docs=Docs2.getAttributes().get("ExternalUNCLink");
        // Fails, something, something: var Selected2Docs=Docs2.getAttributes().values("ExternalUNCLink");
        var Selected2Docs=Docs2.toString().valueOf();
        doc2Array.push(Selected2Docs);
}
getComponent("Docs2").value=Rows + ": " + @Implode(doc2Array, ",");
//viewScope.put("Documents", @Implode(docArray, ","));
```

Any clues how to access the returned value of ExternalUNCLink?

Caveat: I'm not a Domino developer, so excuse me if some of the terminology is incorrect.

[EDIT]

We have a JDBC driver, which lives in the Packages -> Web Content -> WEB-INF -> jdbc folder with a test name and four criterea in an XML style format, thus:

```
<jdbc>
    <driver>net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver</driver>
    <url>jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://malbec/aps_dsql</url>
    <user>user</user>
    <password>pass</password>
</jdbc>
```

Then on the page we have an SQL query in the afterPageLoad event:

```
var TmpSql="select * from TABLE"
viewScope.put("SQLQuery", TmpSql );
getComponent("strSQLQuery").value=TmpSql;
```

After that, you put the viewScope variable "SQLQuery" into the value field for sqlQuery on a JDBCQuery view, using the connectionName variable of the name of the JDBC driver shown above. It returns the data, but we can't seem to access it.

[/EDIT]

[EDIT2]

(with apologies for the dogs breakfast ...)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core"
    xmlns:xc="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/custom">

    <xp:this.afterPageLoad><![CDATA[#{javascript:var TmpSql="select A.extName,A.extUNC,A.extObjInstID,LEFT(A.extUNC,5) as Category, B.cltMailName From cdblink A inner join cdbClientMaster B on A.extobjinstid=B.objInstID where extobjectid=1 and extobjinstid in (1536,1871,632)"
viewScope.put("strSQLQuery", TmpSql);
getComponent("strSQLQuery").value=TmpSql;
getComponent('viewPanelDocs').getData().refresh();
}]]></xp:this.afterPageLoad>
    <xc:testjdbcrowdataaccess></xc:testjdbcrowdataaccess>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="complete">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:
// --var vp=getComponent("viewPanelDocs");
// --
// --//var test=vp._xspGetRendererData().getParent();
// --//var test=vp._xspGetStateId().valueOf();
// --//var test= vp.getChildren().lastIndexOf();
// --var test= vp.getChildren().size();
// --var test=vp.getChildCount();
// --var test=vp._xspGetStateId().valueOf();
// --//var test=vp._xspGetReadOnlyObj().hashCode();
// --//var test=vp.getAttributes().get();
// --var test=vp.getFamily().valueOf();
// --var test=vp.getParent();
// --
// --getComponent("Test").value=test.toString();

//var database=mssql_test.jdbc;
//
//var viewPanel=getComponent("viewPanelDocs");// get the componet of viewPanel
//var docIDArray=viewPanel.getSelectedIds(); //get the array of document ids
//for(i=0; i < docIDArray.length; i++){
 //   var docId=docIDArray[i];
  //  var doc=database.getDocumentByID(docId); 
    // .. your code to deal with the selected document

//    getComponent("Test").value=doc.toString();
//}

var test = getComponent("viewPanelDocs").value;
@ErrorMessage("ID: "+test);}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler></xp:button>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br>
    <xp:br></xp:br><xp:table id="DEBUG" style="width:100%">
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>inputText2</xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:inputText id="inputText2" value="#{viewScope.searchDOCID}" style="width:100%">
                    <xp:eventHandler event="onfocus" submit="true" refreshMode="complete" id="eventHandler2">
                        <xp:this.action>
                            <![CDATA[#{javascript:
                                var viewPanel:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspViewPanel = getComponent('viewPanel2');
                                var dominoView:com.ibm.xsp.model.domino.DominoViewData = viewPanel.getData();
                                var filterValue = getComponent('inputText2').getValue();
                                if (filterValue == 'NA') {
                                filterValue = '';}
                                viewScope.clear()
                                dominoView.setKeys(filterValue);}]]>
                        </xp:this.action>
                    </xp:eventHandler>
                </xp:inputText>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>inputText3 (displayvar)</xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:inputText id="inputText3" value="#{viewScope.documentDOCID}" style="width:100%">
                </xp:inputText>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>Test</xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:inputText id="Test" style="width:100%" value="#{viewScope.test}">
                </xp:inputText>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>inputText1</xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:inputText id="inputText1" style="width:100%"></xp:inputText>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>inputText4</xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:inputText id="inputText4" style="width:100%"></xp:inputText>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>SQLQuery</xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:inputText id="strSQLQuery" style="width:100%" defaultValue="strSQLQuery">
                </xp:inputText>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>SQLQueryCat</xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:inputText id="strSQLQueryCat" style="width:100%">
                </xp:inputText></xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>Doc1</xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:inputText id="Docs" style="width:100%">
</xp:inputText>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td style="width:15%">Doc2</xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:inputText id="Docs2" style="width:100%"></xp:inputText>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>scopeVariable.Documents</xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:inputText id="svDocuments" style="width:100%"></xp:inputText>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
        <xp:tr>
            <xp:td>scopeVariable.Recipients</xp:td>
            <xp:td>
                <xp:inputText id="svRecipients" style="width:100%"></xp:inputText>
            </xp:td>
        </xp:tr>
    </xp:table></xp:view>
```

[/EDIT2]

Comment: A viewPanel isn't designed to show anything but a Notes View. I wonder what you did to coerce the ViewPanel to show an SQL result. Have you eventually used a data table?

Comment: Told you to stay away from SQL

Comment: Updated question to show method of viewing SQL data in a view table ...

Comment: Unfortunately - half of our data is in Notes, and half is in a "pseudo-DMS" which stores it's info in MSSQL ...

Comment: The code is still incomplete - left to guess what exactly happens. Full XPage if you want to solve this. Btw. Did you add the debug control that shows all properties of a control? A ViewPanel is meant for a NotesView. It shouldn't take SQL data. That's what a data table does.

Comment: Sorry, got postponed by another issue, then S/O was giving me some grief about formatting ... although I had it ready when I commented, it's now up :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the answer to my question is a three part one - firstly we use the Domino side of things to get the boxes which are checked, thus:

```
var Docs2=getComponent("viewPanelDocs");
var APKArray=Docs2.getSelectedIds();
//getComponent("svDocuments").value=@Implode(APKArray,",");
```

Then we use the OpenNTF "Model" Java code to get an array of the documents inside the SQL selection:

```
// get the Array from the SQL selection
var namesArray=[];
var PathArray=[];
var locationArray = [];
var FinalNames=[];
var FinalLocations=[];

var Model:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspViewColumn = getComponent("xxxviewColumn3");
var modelData=Model.getDataModel();
var Rows = Model.getChildCount().valueOf();
namesArray.push(Rows);
for(i=0; i < modelData.getRowCount(); i++) {
    modelData.setRowIndex(i);
    var x=modelData.getRowIndex();
    var y=modelData.getRowData().getColumnValue("ExternalName").toString();
    var z=modelData.getRowData().getColumnValue("ExternalUNCLink").toString();
    namesArray.push(x);
    locationArray.push(y);
    PathArray.push(z);
}                       
//getComponent("Docs2").value=namesArray
```

Then we use the index from the Domino side, to reference the names on the SQL side, and put that into a new array:

```
// put the selected docs in the selected array

for(i=0; i < APKArray.length; i++) {
    var z = APKArray[i].valueOf();
    FinalNames.push(PathArray[z].valueOf() + "\\" + locationArray[z].valueOf())
    //FinalLocations.push(locationArray[z].valueOf())
}

getComponent("Docs2").value=@Implode(FinalNames,",");
```

The Path + Names ends up in the Docs2 edit box. It's pretty messy, but works (I hope this doesn't ruin my caveat!!)

Answer (score 1):

When you have a [ViewPanel](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSVRGU_9.0.0/com.ibm.designer.domino.ui.doc/wpd_controls_cref_viewpanel.html) that is linked to a Notes View, the selected documents can be found using the `getSelectedIds()` method on the viewPanel object. You then can [loop through the values](https://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/2008-11-11033022WEBBZ4.htm) to get the documents and their full URLs:

```
var viewPanel=getComponent("viewPanel1");get the componet of viewPanel
var docIDArray=viewPanel.getSelectedIds(); get the array of document ids
for(i=0; i < docIDArray.length; i++){
    var docId=docIDArray[i];
    var doc=database.getDocumentByID(docId); 
    // .. your code to deal with the selected document
}
```

Might work for your JDBC use case too.

Comment: Appreciate your answer, but how to access the "database" variable - the code is saying that "doc" is null:

    Error while executing JavaScript action expression
    Script interpreter error, line=23, col=36: 'doc' is null

Comment: database is a global variable. However I suspect you didn’t use a view panel simply bound to a view. So update your question with the actual xpage source. Otherwise we play a guessing game

Comment: Happy to put it up, but it's a bit of a chop-shop job, I've got it down to it's most raw form ...

Comment: var viewPanel:com.ibm.xsp.component.xp.XspViewPanel = getComponent('viewPanel2'); ->> there is no viewPanel2 component on your page

Comment: This is the working code from a bigger project - the viewPanel2 is part of the bigger project - the DEBUG section (table) is where I'm putting the values for what I need to see, the only value for this watered down code I'm using is the "strSQLQuery" text box, which shows the SQL string being fed to the database (so I can confirm it works in a SQL viewer program) ... hope that explains it ...